# JSON.Net VB deserialize not working

Tags: vb.net, json, json.net

I'm new to VB and trying to write a webservice that exports and imports JSON.

I'm using JSON.NET 3.5 and can serialize fine:

My Token class is:

```
<DataContract()> _
  Public Class Token
    <DataMember()> _
    Public TokenID As String

    <DataMember()> _
    Public Issued As Date

    <DataMember()> _
    Public Expires As Date

    <DataMember()> _
    Public UserName As String

    <DataMember()> _
    Public CompanyID As String

    <DataMember()> _
    Public ApplicationID As Double

    <DataMember()> _
    Public UserID As Double

    <DataMember()> _
    Public DeviceID As Double

    <DataMember()> _
    Public DeviceSerialNumber As String

    <DataMember()> _
    Public IsValid As Boolean

    <DataMember()> _
    Public DebugText As String
```

(I started with MS's serialization but thought i'd try JSON.NET)

I serialize with:

Dim ThisToken as New Token
ThisToken.DebugText = "blah"
and so on

```
    JSONString = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ThisToken)
```

And I get this output from the webservice:

{"TokenID":"9eaae348-5cbd-46ac-8ba9-83720ac07740","Issued":"/Date(1300422761886+0800)/","Expires":"/Date(1300465961886+0800)/","UserName":"1234","CompanyID":"6","ApplicationID":1.0,"UserID":29.0,"DeviceID":1.0,"DeviceSerialNumber":"9149520800758","IsValid":true,"DebugText":""}

So far so good I think.

To test that deserialization is working, I thought i'd try and deserialise what I just serialised. So I create a webservice that accepts a string and I paste the above into it.

code to deseralise is:

```
    Dim ThisToken As New Token

    ThisToken = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(JSonString)
```

When I run the code using VS2005 internal debug/IE testing, I get an http500 internal server error.

I also get the same problem if I try to deserialize immediately after serializing.

I think part of the problem is that the code I was following was c#; from the json.net page:

```
Product deserializedProduct = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Product>(json);
```

I can see that in c# there is a `<Product>` part which is not readily apparant in vb ?

I have no doubt that the newtonsoft json.net product works fine; I'm sure that i'm not doing something right.

Help ?

Andrew

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The VB equivalent to

```
Product deserializedProduct = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Product>(json);
```

is

```
Dim deserializedProduct as Product = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Product)(Json)
```

So I think you want

```
Dim ThisToken as Token = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Token)(JSonString)
```

Comment: I'll need to register and login and hopefully can then do the vote & mark as complete thing.. andrew

Comment: What if I dont have a class/type to deserialize to? Like I have this statement in c#, dynamic deserializedProduct = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json); What would be the equivalent of this on VB.NET? see question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13890267/vb-net-deserialize-json-to-anonymous-object-using-newtonsoft-returned-error

Comment: I think in vb.net you need to create class to deserialize. Otherwise switch to .NET 4