# VB.NET Deserialize JSON to anonymous object using newtonsoft returned error

Tags: vb.net, json, json.net

I would like to deserialize the returned JSON from a service call in VB.NET to an anonymous type but I was having error. It works in C# using dynamic type but i dont know how to do it in VB.

Here is my JSON returned from a web service call:

`{"format":"png","height":564,"width":864}`

Here is my VB code json above assigned to param text:

```
Dim testObj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(text)
```

But when i tried to access testObj.format, an exception was thrown with message

```
{"Public member 'format' on type 'JObject' not found."}
```

I already have added `Option Strict Off`. I dont want to use an Object/Class to deserialize the JSON. If its in C# assigning this to dynamic type will be working fine.

Can anyone please help? I am not expert in VB but I need to have this running on VB. TIA

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim js As New System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer
Dim testObj = js.Deserialize(source, New Object().GetType())
```

Then you can access the key(attribute name)/values via:

```
value=testobj(key)
```

One more thing, you can access your Newtonsoft key(attribute name)/values through:

```
value=testObj.item(key)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim js As New System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer
Dim DeSerialObjEventData = New With {.Prop1 = String.Empty, .Prop2 = String.Empty, .Prop3 = String.Empty}...
Dim testObj = js.DeserializeAnnonomusType(source, DeSerialObjEventData)
```